# Entity Framework Many To Many Relationship is adding "end" items BEFORE adding the relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have set up a very simple entity framework Database first project using the common Students and Courses scenario.

- A student can have many courses
- A course can have many students

I have set up the relationship in the database and EF has created a nice Many to Many navigation item for this.

**The problem** when I add a course to a student, the course gets RE-ADDED to the course table THEN the relationship gets added to the database, resulting in an every growing number of duplicated courses

this is driving me nuts, any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Some of my code....

I have created a Partial class over an above the entity generated one, so that I can have a EditorTemplate with a check box, this will allow the user to tick the course to add

```
public partial class Course
{
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }
}

public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

The Editor Template for the courses

```
@model University.Models.Course

<div>
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isSelected)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CourseName)


    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CourseName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m =>m.CourseId)
</div>
```

The Create Student View

```
@model University.Models.CreateStudentViewModel            
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Student</legend>            
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.student.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.student.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.student.Name)
        </div>    
        <div>        
            @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.courses)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

The ViewModel for the page

```
public class CreateStudentViewModel
{
    public Student student { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Course> courses { get; set; }
}
```

The Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    CreateStudentViewModel vm = new CreateStudentViewModel();
    vm.courses = db.Courses.ToList();
    return View(vm);
} 
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateStudentViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.student.Courses = model.courses.Where(m => m.isSelected == true).ToList();
        db.Students.Add(model.student);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Any help pointing me in the correct direction would be GREATLY appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must *attach* the selected courses to the context in your post action *before* you add the student to the context. Otherwise EF assumes that the whole object graph - student including all courses - is *new* and must be *inserted* into the database. By attaching (=putting the courses into `Unchanged` state) you tell EF that you don't want the attached courses to be inserted as new rows but only create a relationship between the new student and the existing courses:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateStudentViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.student.Courses =
            model.courses.Where(m => m.isSelected == true).ToList();

        foreach (var course in model.student.Courses)
            db.Courses.Attach(course);
        // now each course is in state Unchanged in the context

        db.Students.Add(model.student);
        // model.student is in state Added in the context
        // but the courses still have the state Unchanged.
        // Without the attach-loop above they would be in
        // state Added as well, which will create new courses
        // in the DB after SaveChanges

        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: sounds sensible, I will try it out Monday! Thank you