# Entity Framework code first many-to-many relationship CREATE view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, many-to-many

I'm new to MVC and Entity Framework in general. For studies, I'm developing a website where there is a page for create a product to be sold in the website...
One product can have many applications and one application can be used with many diferent products. 
e.g.: product id:1 name: chair, applications: to sit, to burn 
      product id:2 name: table, applications: to burn
      application id:1 name: to sit 
      application id:2 name: to burn

Product class

```
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
```

Application class

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Context file:

```
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public DbSet<Application > Applications { get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Applications).WithMany(i => i.Products)
                .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("ProductId")
                    .MapRightKey("ApplicationId")
                    .ToTable("ProductApplication"));
```

My questions:

1) Are my entities right for what I want to do? I mean, the EF will create a bridge table to link those two tables (Product and Application)?

2) How can I make the Create view display all the Applications that are available in the DB for the users choose as many applications as they desire to the product they're creating?

EDIT

So, my EF created the bridge table ProductApplication as I wanted, so far so good.

In my create view, I list all the Application available in DB like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Applications, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @foreach (Application app in ViewBag.Aplications)
            {
                <input type="checkbox" id="@app.Id" name="Applications"/>@app.Nome
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is displays them ok, but when I submit, the object Product sent to the action have the Applications property equals 0.

I need this Product to have the applications that were selected on the view, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `WithMany(i => i.Applications)`. For the rest, the question how to create *a view* is too broad. You'll get more help if you try something and show your efforts.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8186580/861716) is a duplicate. But there are more similar posts.